# Bluetooth headset prevents YouTube videos from playing. How do I fix this?

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth, headphones, youtube

I'm reading this [similar issue over on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/731201/when-bluetooth-is-enabled-youtube-spotify-soundcloud-stops-working/743783), and I have the same problem. I have a new Bluetooth headset that I can listen with on my Mac OS 10.14.6, but occasionally, YouTube videos will load whatever frame I navigate to, but will completely refuse to play.

[These are the headphones I bought](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DXSYJ5N). This is fixed both when I completely disable Bluetooth (though then my 3mm jack headphones don't work), and when I simply disconnect the Bluetooth headphones.

Is there any sort of advanced configuration for Bluetooth in Mac OS? The settings I'm seeing don't seem to be capable of fixing this.

Here are the Audio MIDI Setup options:

[image: UBI 2 settings]

[image: UBI 2 formats]

[image: UBI 1 microphone settings]

Comment: Quick test - Applications/Utilities/Audio MIDI Setup. Choose your device, change the  Output format from 44 to 48 [or vice versa] then change back again. Try to play the video [may need you to reload the page]

Comment: I can change from `2 ch 32-bit Float 48.0 kHz` to `1 ch 16-bit Ingeter 16.0 kHz`, but I don't see an option for 44 kHz.

Comment: Available options will be device-driven. Usually the 'simple' ones are 44.1 & 48… I'm surprised one is float rather than integer, but I usually deal in 'pro audio' interfaces not bluetooth, so idk how they will present.

Comment: @Tetsujin I added screenshots of the Audio MIDI Setup. It just stalled YouTube again and I think it was on 16-bit. I'll keep it on 16-bit for a while to see if it keeps acting up.

Comment: I think it may not be the issue I was thinking of. I've had some devices since Mojave that will stall all 'media players' until the codec is toggled, which seems to wake it up. If toggling the available options doesn't produce an immediate [albeit temporary] fix, then it's unlikely to be what I'd first considered.